# ggplot over many data frames changing titles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have many data frames which are the output of the same kind of analysis but with different parameters.
I'd like to plot the data frames with `ggplot`, changing the main title to specify the different parameters used.

I thought about putting the data frames into a list and using `lapply`. But I couldn't figure out how to change the title accordingly in `lapply`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this,

```
parameters = data.frame(p1=letters[1:5], p2=round(rnorm(5),2))
l = replicate(5, data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10)), simplify=FALSE)
names(l) = do.call(paste, c(parameters, sep=","))

plot_one = function(x)
  ggplot(data = l[[x]]) + geom_path(aes(x, y)) +
   opts(title = x)

plots = lapply(names(l), plot_one)

do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, plots)
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Brilliant. I didn't think of using names of a list as a key to call the values. lapply and do.call combo looks very handy.